# QR code with multibyte characters

Tags: barcode, qr-code, zxing, multibyte

Jdev 11.1.2.2.0

I have to generate a QR bar-code for my application and for which I have used zxing by google to achieve the same. It is working well when scanned for text, numbers and special characters. But when I give any other language than English and scan the bar-code, it is displaying every character as a question mark.

How do I achieve QR bar-code generation for multi byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify to Zxing generator you'll use UTF-8 character set, with an EncodeHint parameter, as described [in the doc](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter.html#encode-java.lang.String-com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat-int-int-java.util.Map-).

> encode(String content, ErrorCorrectionLevel ecLevel,
>   **Map hints**)

http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.html#CHARACTER_SET :

> **CHARACTER_SET**
>
> public static final EncodeHintType CHARACTER_SET
>
> Specifies what character encoding to use where applicable (type
>   String)

You also have to be sure the string you pass to the generator are in the correct character set.

Comment: Thanks Veve, I have done that . 

I have followed the below blog for implementing QR code

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code/